# Magento 2 : Getting Controller URL

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers, geturl

I am trying to get controller URL in my Block, but I am not able to get it. I tried this code :

```
$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getDefaultStoreView()->getStoreId();
$url = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getUrl("zipcode/index/index");
```

This code throws an exception like :

> Undefined property: Tm\Zipcode\Helper\Data::$_storeManager

I can access controller manually at `store_name/zipcode/index/index`

Comment: `$url = $this->getUrl('zipcode/index/index');`

Comment: I tried that too, it shows _undefined method getUrl()_

Comment: r u extend your block class with `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` ?

Comment: @Bhavik yes I did it.

Answer (score 6):

if you have created your block class by extending **\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template**

In Your phtml file use following code :

> $block->getUrl("zipcode/index/index");

To get the url.

if you need the url in the block class itself use :

> $this->getUrl("zipcode/index/index");

Comment if you need more help.

Comment: I need the URL in the block class itself, not in the phtml. file

Comment: then use `$this->getUrl(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `Tm\Zipcode\Helper\Data` class and make the constructor look like this

```
protected $_storeManager;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $_storeManager,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_storeManager = $_storeManager;
    ...
}
```

Then the `storeManager` variable will be available in your class